# Логирование в модулях

Tags: golang

Уже всю голову себе стесал, но так и не нашёл ответ на свой вопрос. Может проблема, что я перешёл на Go с Python и некоторые парадигмы просто не могу перенести на другой язык.

Если я настраиваю логирование в основном модуле в файл, как я могу подключиться к этому же логеру во вложенном модуле и писать лог туда же?

К примеру main.go:

```
package main

log = logmain.New(...)
```

как мне в модуле lib/module.go получить ссылку на логер из main:

```
package lib

func Test() {
  log = ?
}
```

Пишут, что это зависимость и нужно явно передавать вызываемому модулю ссылку на логгер, но это придется все отдельные функции объединять в структуру, типа:

```
package lib

type Work struct {
  log *log.Logger
}

func (m *Work) Test() {
  m.log.Print(...)
}
```

что пока мне видится диковато.
Может можно как-то через в init() модуля подключиться к логеру из main?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Вариант с методом не "диковат", а вполне логичен. Разве что я в своей работе как правило абстрагирую:

```
type Logger interface {
    Printf(string, ...interface{})
}

type Foo struct {
    logger Logger
}

func NewFoo(logger Logger) *Foo {
    return &Foo{
        logger: logger,
    }
}
```

Это позволяет заменять логгер, например, в тестах.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю - в Go вообще нет глобальных объектов, к которым можно получать доступ из подчинённых модулей? И получается, единственный способ - это передача данных через структуры или параметры функций?

Comment: @kirsrus Из подключаемых - нет. Вы можете сделать в модуле глобальную переменную и заставить клиентов в main'е, или где они используют ваш модуль, её устанавливать, но КМК это так себе решение.

Answer (score 0):

Вторую неделю смотрю на Go.
Вот от [сюда](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2013/11/using-log-package-in-go.html)
получился похожий эм.. класс:

```
package log

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

var (
    Trace   *log.Logger
    Info    *log.Logger
    Warning *log.Logger
    Error   *log.Logger
)

func InitLogger() {

    file_name := "./test_ms.log"
    file, err := os.OpenFile(file_name, os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to open log file ", file_name, ":", err)
    }

    Trace = log.New(file,
        "TRACE: ",
        log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    Info = log.New(file,
        "INFO: ",
        log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    Warning = log.New(file,
        "WARNING: ",
        log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    Error = log.New(file,
        "ERROR: ",
        log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
}
```

В main будет init:

```
package main

import (
    log "./log"
)

func main() {

    log.InitLogger()
```

В любом пакете импортировать и можно писать

```
log.Info.Println("Start HTTP server.")
```

Кажется для goland это нормально